# How to send only message from android messenge application

Tags: java, android, api, sdk, messenger

Please i'm new to Android , and i have been developping an application in the style of Messenger for a Week (researching and trying to understand code ... etc) which consists on sending a message to friends i have on facebook . Thus the message is sent , it contains a picture . My question is how can i send only the message

Here is so far my code for the part of the activity that does the sending:
 ` private void onMessengerButtonClicked() {

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://inboxapp.example.com.inboxapp/" + R.drawable.cover);

    // Create the parameters for what we want to send to Messenger.
    ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
            ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(uri, "image/jpeg")
                    .setMetaData("{ \"image\" : \"tree\" }")
                    .build();

    if (mPicking) {
        // If we were launched from Messenger, we call MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger to return
        // the content to Messenger.
        MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger(this, shareToMessengerParams);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, we were launched directly (for example, user clicked the launcher icon). We
        // initiate the broadcast flow in Messenger. If Messenger is not installed or Messenger needs
        // to be upgraded, this will direct the user to the play store.
        MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
                this,
                REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
                shareToMessengerParams);
    }
}`
```

Please i'm stuck on that level and i saw that SDK 4.x does not allow this anymore , is there no possible workaround?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried placing null or leaving it empty

Passing null value for image.

```
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
        ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(uri, "null")
                .setMetaData("{ \"image\" : \"tree\" }")
                .build();
```

Passing empty value for image.

```
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
        ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(uri, "")
                .setMetaData("{ \"image\" : \"tree\" }")
                .build();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but my app crashes when i try to make the value = "" or null without giving any errors . Thank you